# PHP: How to know if a PostgreSQL persistent connection is already opened?

Tags: php, postgresql, persistent-connection

According to PHP.net manual, pg_pconnect will create a persistent connection, or will return the existing one if it already exists with same connection string.

The problem I have is I want to know whether that call indeed creates a connection or actually returns the same, for example, for loading prepared statements in case it is the first connection.

Can it actually be possible?

UPDATE:
With this question I am not referring to the current running PHP script. I want to know if the connection has been opened *sometime* (maybe by other scripts another time) or this script is the first in open that connection (for example, because I resetted the PostgreSQL server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manual. Solution is given in its description itself. It returns the existing connection if you have enabled persistent connection, which is the enabled by default. I had no problem with it in my experience. Hope this helps out. [php.net manual for pg_pconnect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-pconnect.php)

ANSWER UPDATED: i should add that normally postgres is very possesive towards its connections; it tries to retain the connections even if you reset the service; so it would be wise not use this event of "checking a pre-existing connection" as even if u found a mechanism to detect the new connection returned event, it will be countable by your fingers; very few very rare.

I think you should shift your logic.

Comment: I should have clarified a bit my question, I am sorry for missunderstanding. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: i hope you had read this http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: Yes, I have read that. Thank you, this was just an idea, not implemented yet, but yes. It seems I need to load the prepared sentence anytime I open the connection (despite it may be already opened) and just ignore if it fails because it is already loaded?